# Конкатенация строк в Excel или как сформировать динамическую строку

Tags: c#, excel

Есть функция, которая тянет данные из кода по шаблону

Где (Тест, ДатаА, ДатаБ, ДатаВ) это, переменные в которые подставляются данные из кода.

func(152; Тест <> 106;  ДатаА + 9 < ДатаБ <= ДатаВ + 38)
Так всё работает, но цифры (9 и 38) и т.д. нужно заполнять в ручную

```
func(152; Тест <> 106;  ДатаА + 38 < ДатаБ <= ДатаВ + 47)
func(152; Тест <> 106;  ДатаА + 47 < ДатаБ <= ДатаВ + 85)
```

мне нужно привязать цифры к ячейкам. То есть сделать так

```
func(152; Тест <> 106;  ДатаА + А7 < ДатаБ <= ДатаВ + А8)
```

но, так как это не excel функция то Excel её видит как простую строку и ячейки не срабатывают в скобках.
За пределами скобок ячейки работают.

Есть ли способ решить данную проблему.

Пробовал СЦЕПИТЬ(...) но так как func функция не Excel то теперь строка получилась но код не воспринимает её.
Так как в начале стоит =СЦЕПИТЬ(...)

Так же пробовал $А7, A7&

Comment: *"текст1 " & переменна & " текст2"...*

Comment: @vikttur `func(152; Тест <> 106;  ДатаА +" & А7 & " < ДатаБ <= ДатаВ + " & А8 & " ) "` Сделал так но к сожалению не работает :( По прежнему `A7 и A8` являться просто текстом, а не ячейкой.